# Automatically update financial year variable yearly

Tags: excel, vba

I have a variable that saves the start date of the current financial year which starts from 1st April as `CurrentFY = #1/4/2020#` in a `#d/m/yyyy#` format

This means that when 1st April 2021 arrives, i have to manually update this variable to `CurrentFY = #1/4/2021#`. Is there a way to automatically update this variable yearly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to "update" anything, as you can create your `CurrentFY` dynamically:

```
CurrentFY = DateSerial(Year(DateAdd("m", -3, Date)), 4, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a string dynamically and then convert it to date like so:

```
CurrentFY = CDate("1/4/" & Year(Date))
```

That way, any time the code runs, Year(Date) gives you year of current date.

Comment: This will return _2021-04-04_ in the first quarter of 2021 while it should return _2020-04-01_.

Comment: @Gustav I'd like to learn a bit more from your example. Can you elaborate how a string "1/4/2021" return "4/4/2021" in the first quarter of 2021? It seems like the OP is in a country where date is formatted dd/mm/yyyy i.e. 1/4 is 1st April.

Comment: Yes, we use the same format here, and your expression correctly returns April here, but in, say, the US it would return January. That can be avoided by using DateSerial with its specific parameters. As for the year, with your expression is fixed to the calendar year where it should be offset by a quarter.

Comment: @Gustav If I am understanding correctly, the downvote is (assuming you downvoted) because you expected the answer to target US audience. OP is not expecting that in the question. Your answer may be versatile. That doesn't make my answer incorrect for the OP. The OP is not expecting offsets. The OP is literally expecting 1st April based on my understanding of the question. OP is just wanting dynamic year.

Comment: Yes. As I noted, today it will return _2021-04-01_ and not _2020-04-01_ which is the current FY, and it will not change when reaching April. Alternatively, as the questioneer has accepted the answer, the question should be rephrased.

Comment: @Gustav ah, yes, I get now. Thank you.